# How to access a global resource in an asynchronous context?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-async-std

I've been writing a small web service with the `tide` framework in the `async-std` flavor. The project uses a database that is used sparsely but throughout the entire project.

I thought it would be reasonable to declare it as a global variable, so that I wouldn't have to include in almost every function interface, just for it to be passed along unused. After a bit of arguing with the compiler about the number of Rust design principles that I was breaking, I settled on the following declaration:

```rust
pub static DATABASE: RwLock<Database> = const_rwlock(Database::new());
```

`const_rwlock()` is a constant `Rwlock` constructor from the `parking_lot` crate (the same as the `RwLock` on nightly as far as I know) and `Database` is my own type that gets later filled with the connection details and handles the actual communication and initialization of the database in asynchronous manner.

Everything looked alright, as I could use it like so:

```rust
let data = DATABASE.read().get_data(&key).await;
```

even with async methods in async functions.

The problem arises when I try to pass this functionality into the web framework. I'm supposed to do so by passing in an async block closure that has to be `Send`, but when I write something like this:

```rust
// the actual function to start the servers looks essentially like this
start_server(|| async move {
    // this is run asynchronously for every connection by the framework
    let token = do_stuff();

    let result = DATABASE.read().check(token).await;
});
```

I get an error, because the entire future is no longer `Send`. It makes sense to me, because I'm locking a mutex with the `.read()` call, and then packing the entire thing into a future and awaiting it. That means that the locked mutex might be sent to another thread, which doesn't seem sensible.

This leads me to think that I designed the entire global variable wrong and I have no better ideas.

What would be a good way to represent a resource that is used in many places in async code? I'd like to avoid the "pass it everywhere" route.

This is a somewhat minimal code example. I extracted the relevant code from the `tide` crate to try and reduce the scope of this question.

```rust
use async_std::sync::Arc;
use parking_lot::{const_rwlock, RwLock};
use std::future::Future;

pub static DATABASE: RwLock<Database> = const_rwlock(Database::new());
// const mutex can only be constructed with new() on nightly
//pub static DATABASE: RwLock<Database> = RwLock::new(Database::new());

pub struct Database {
    // Here would be the actual connection stored
    pool: Option<()>,
}

impl Database {
    const fn new() -> Self {
        Database {
            pool: None,
        }
    }

    pub async fn init(&mut self) {
        self.pool = Some(());
    }

    pub async fn check(&self, token: &str) -> bool {
        if token == "vibe" {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

#[async_std::main]
async fn main() {
    DATABASE.read().init().await;

    Server::new(|| async move {
        // XXX There's the problem
        let result = DATABASE.read().check("vibe").await;

        if result {
            Ok(())
        } else {
            Err(())
        }
    });
}

// Everything below is part of some library and can't be changed by me

struct Server<H> {
    handler: Arc<H>
}

impl<H, Fut> Server<H>
where
    // Those requirements are verbatim copied from the framework code
    H: Fn() -> Fut + Sync + Send + 'static,
    Fut: Future<Output = Result<(), ()>> + Send + 'static,
{
    pub fn new(handler: H) -> Self {
        Self {
            handler: Arc::new(handler),
        }
    }
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "server"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
parking_lot = "0.11"
async-std = { version = "1.6", features = ["attributes"] }
```

After running `cargo check` on it, I get the described error:

```
    Checking server v0.1.0 (/XXX/server)
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:36:5
   |
36 |     Server::new(|| async move {
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ future created by async block is not `Send`
...
60 |     pub fn new(handler: H) -> Self {
   |     ------------------------------ required by `Server::<H>::new`
   |
   = help: within `impl Future`, the trait `std::marker::Send` is not implemented for `*mut ()`
note: future is not `Send` as this value is used across an await
  --> src/main.rs:38:22
   |
38 |         let result = DATABASE.read().check("vibe").await;
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ first, await occurs here, with `DATABASE.read()` maybe used later...
note: `DATABASE.read()` is later dropped here
  --> src/main.rs:38:57
   |
38 |         let result = DATABASE.read().check("vibe").await;
   |                      ---------------                    ^
   |                      |
   |                      has type `parking_lot::lock_api::RwLockReadGuard<'_, parking_lot::RawRwLock, Database>` which is not `Send`
help: consider moving this into a `let` binding to create a shorter lived borrow
  --> src/main.rs:38:22
   |
38 |         let result = DATABASE.read().check("vibe").await;
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I believe I interpreted this error correctly at a high level (can't move lock guard between threads) and it is explained on low level (`*mut ()` is not `Send`) in this error message.

Comment: What's the error? I'd like to know exactly why it's not `Send`. Also, I'm not comfortable enough with the implementation to give you a proper answer, but I think you can solve this with actors--assign one actor that's in charge of doing DB stuff. Or a single-worker thread pool with a thread-local DB handle, but you're better off using a common pattern than a hack.

Comment: @piojo because a lock guard would not normally be `Send`. Unlocking from a different thread you locked in is usually either UB or plain guaranteed not to work. Neither the stdlib's nor parking_lot's guard are `Send`.

Comment: @veproject Globals are generally not a good idea in Rust, and "pass it around everywhere" (with the relevant Rc/Arc around) is usually considered a better idea. But whichever solution you pick, here you'll probably need to use async-aware synchronisation primitives.

Comment: Here's (async-std's implementation of `RwLock`](https://docs.rs/async-std/1.9.0/async_std/sync/struct.RwLock.html. The `new()` method is const, so it can be initialized in const context.